# how to configure dynamic urls in httpd.conf file for reverse proxy

Tags: ajax, apache, httpd.conf

I am using apache httpd server for reverse proxy to make cross domain ajax calls.

ProxyPass /v1/virtuals http://mypage.com/:4277/v1/virtuals/abc

ProxyPassReverse /v1/virtuals  http://mypage.com:4277/v1/virtuals/xyz

in the above url the abc,xyz  will be changed based on the selection.those will be dynamic.so how could i configure the urls with that dynamic content in httpd.conf file

Answer (score 0):

Tried with wild card pattern. but it is not working.

http://mypage.com/:4277/v1/virtuals/

in httpd.conf is sufficient to allow all the urls